# Tempdb disk getting full in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Currently we are facing issue with `tempdb` which was allocated with 200 GB. Mostly disk is getting full 2 times/day and with help of DBA, spaces are clearing by using shrink statement.

Three months before server was re-started suddenly after which `tempdb` issues started. We checked with db team to identify any option were disabled which were related to clear the log automatically. But they confirmed everything were looks fine.

Can you tell me where to start as we don't have access to system tables in production system?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If ever there was a job for a DBA then this is it, pass it over to them.

Comment: @MJH - due to disk full all critical packages are getting fail and impacting the business..

Comment: You don't have access to system tables, so how are you going to look into this issue?  Your DBAs are there to sort problems like this out.

Comment: I want to know the options like clear the temp space or logs automatically as we used to have this functionality previously.Please let me know ?